# switchvox api: what is a simple REST call I can make, XML or json, to validate the server is accepting API calls?

Tags: asterisk, switchvox

What is a basic REST call I can make, using fiddler or curl, to do simple interaction w the switchvox api, just to see that it is handling api calls?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a curl example (quoted for use on curl on windows) that can be used to do this (put it all on one line):

```
curl -k -H "Content-Type: application/json" --data "{\"request\": {\"method\": 
\"switchvox.call\",
\"parameters\": {\"dial_first\": \"1927\",\"dial_second\": \"12226660000\",
\"dial_as_account_id\": \"1127\"}}}" 
--verbose --basic --user api_admin:####### https://myserver/json
```

Comment: do you have a link where you found the decimation for this?   The developer site, seems to only show XML examples and is quite dated.

Comment: @JimHankins You are right. The dev site is in bad need of update. I don't know where we discovered the json api (another guy built this thing), but what I do is convert the xml to json, and it works.